# ansible IOS_Config timeout override

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to override the timeout on ansible? I'm sending around 700 lines of Cisco iOS config. However I get a timeout error:

```
ansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: timeout trying to send command
```

Is there a way to increase the timeout so I can send the full set of lines?

```
- hosts: 192.168.1.1
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
  - name: send config
    ios_config:
      lines:
        -config 
        -config
```

Comment: can you [edit] the question and provide the version of ansible you use please

Answer (score 1):

They are two tunables for timeout, `persistent_connect_timeout` and `persistent_command_timeout`. The latter seems to be one you have to change. 
You have to edit `ansible.cfg` and put this text

```
[persistent_connection]
command_timeout = 30
```

You can also as a test define the environment variable `ANSIBLE_PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT=30` before launching the playbook so that would apply to all network tasks

Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/network/user_guide/network_debug_troubleshooting.html#timeouts